# Selecting a steam shortcut in python tkinter using filedialog askopenfilename() returns an error

Tags: python, tkinter, steam

I made a very simple program in python that lets me select a file and creates a shortcut at a chosen location of that file. I made this because I often found myself wanting some other apps (mostly games) to be in the startmenu folde, so I could just search for it easily in the windows search bar. This worked surprisingly well (I have no experience in coding) at first, but today I tried adding a shortcut to a steam game, which didn't work at all. As mentioned in the title, I used tkinter to have some sort of graphical interface and used filedialog to select a file which I want to make a shortcut of.

However, selecting a steam game (url shortcut) returned an error message, displaying only the name of the game and "critical error". At first I thought it's because I'm selecting a .url file instead of an .exe or .ink file, but while trying a shortcut to a browser website didn't return the intended result, it at least let me select the file. My problem really is being unable to select the steam game .url file and getting something back, like the directory, link or name of the file.

In case it helps, this is the filedialog snippet of my code:

`filename_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select File", filetypes=((".exe files", "*.exe"), ("all files", "*.*")))`

[This is the error I get (in german, so I'm not sure if it helps)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdYUJ.png)

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and post a [mcve]? Also, please no images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask].

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example so we can copy/paste and run your code? Instead of posting error images please add your error message as text. Also your question is not clear to me, you said in your title "selecting a shortcut" but then you said "select a file and create a shortcut"???